# Create a 2d map to place a robot

Tags: ros, 2d-image

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello. I'm an absolute begginer. Read a while back the book "A gentle introdution to ROS". I need do draw a 2d labyrinth and place a robot, like turtlesim to implement some intelligence and make it move. How can I do it? Can I replace the backgoung of turtlesim with a .png image and make the turtlesim_node detect a colision with a wall by a color? I read about costmap_2d, but I don't want to make a map, I want to have one where my robot with a collision sensor can move through.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/220679/create-a-2d-map-to-place-a-robot/) by [danm](https://answers.ros.org/users/25050/danm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-11-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [donmrsir](https://answers.ros.org/users/19553/donmrsir/) on 2015-11-10**:
Hi! i think you should star searching about 2d simulators in ROS. Since it seems what you are trying to do is just a simple 2d simulation. Gazebo is the most used simulator in ROS, but is for 3d environments, so you should search some altenatives, and learn how to use them with the wiki.

**Comment by [danm](https://answers.ros.org/users/25050/danm/) on 2015-11-11**:
You're right. I'm now using stdr_simulator. Thank you

**Comment by [donmrsir](https://answers.ros.org/users/19553/donmrsir/) on 2015-11-12**:
No problem :D.I will add this comment as an answer then to let other people know that your problem has been solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You could start with [simulating Turtlebot](http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot_simulator). For that you have the choice between Gazebo, stage or STDR. I think the simultion should work out of the box so that you can start playing around with the costmap etc.

---

Originally posted by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) with karma: 3339 on 2015-11-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [danm](https://answers.ros.org/users/25050/danm/) on 2015-11-12**:
turtlebot_simulator seems a good alternative, thank you for mentioning it.